# How to send an email with pass/fail tests on jenkins using editable email notificaiton

Tags: ios, jenkins, junit, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-email-ext

I have a jenkins job that builds an iOS app and runs a test script which posts the results into an xml file using xcpretty.

In the post build actions I publish the results in xml format. Is it possible to get some of the contents of these results and put them into the email notification to send i.e.

Tests Passed: {Number of passed tests}

Tests Failed: {Number of failed tests}

Total Tests: {Total tests}

Answer (score 1):

In your "Execute Shell"

`echo "test log" > /some/file/path/logFile.txt`

Then in your "Editable Email Notification-Default Content"

`${FILE,path="/some/file/path/logFile.txt"}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use attach the XML file to the e-mail and try to use HTML block and add the file name inside. I used it for jpeg file and it worked great.
It's also possible to use a script to examine the file and assign an environment variable, that you'd later use in the content of the email.